# How to solve $\ddot{x}-\omega_0^2x+\beta x^3=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new to differential equation and struggling with this problem.
$$\ddot{x}-\omega_0^2x+\beta x^3=0$$
 Found out this is kind of Duffing equation but I don't know what to do.
Sorry to ask such a basic question but what should be the next step?

Comment: I guess it is related to [Jacobi Elliptic Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html). Moreover, can [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035037/solving-the-nonlinear-differential-equation-m-ddot-x-alpha-x-beta-x3?rq=1) be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dot x\ddot{x}-\omega_0^2x\dot x+\beta x^3\dot x=0$$

and by integration

$$4\dot x^2-4\omega_0^2x^2+2\beta x^4=c.$$

Then

$$2\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c+4\omega_0^2x^2-2\beta x^4}}=t+c'$$ and things get nasty.

Comment: This a relatively nice incomplete elliptic integral. I wouldn't call it nasty :)

Comment: if we rewrite the sign respectively($\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2x-\beta x=0$), would the answer be $2\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c-4\omega_0^2x^2+2\beta x^4}}=t+c'$?

Comment: @YuriyS: are you sure ? WA gives an horrible result, with of course no hope for analytical inversion.

Comment: sorry but could you specify the calculation process from step1 to step2 in a little more detail?

Comment: @J.Maisel: don't you understand "by integration" ? There are no intermediate steps.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, oh, sorry, I meant that it's nice because it's pretty standard, and can be treated by numerical algorithms (Carlson), but I agree that analytical inversion is not possible.